# Can't return a String value and append it...why?

Tags: iphone, string, append

I am writing an app and am having problems returning a simple string value, and I'm not sure why.

The function I am using (within a file called APIManager.m) is:

```
- (NSString*) returnVenueUrl {
NSString *venueUrl = [devEnvironment stringByAppendingString:@"venue/id/"];
return venueUrl;
```

}

I can return this properly by doing this in another .m file:

```
APIManager *apiManager = [APIManager apiManager];
NSLog(@"view venue URL is here: %@", [apiManager returnVenueUrl]);
```

But when I go to append a variable cast as a String onto it, I get nothing..

```
venueURL = [apiManager returnVenueUrl];
venueURL = [venueURL stringByAppendingString:venueId];

NSLog(@"the Full Venue URL is: %", venueURL);
```

If anyone has any advice on how to fix this, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just to ask rather than posting this as the fix. You didn't pull the code examples directly from your code did you?  In the 2nd non working example your NSLog(@"the Full Venue URL is: %", venueURL); line is incorrect you need the "@" after the "%" as such "NSLog(@"the Full Venue URL is: %@", venueURL);"

Comment: Jonathan thanks..you are right..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NSMutableString
NSString is immutable (aka non modifiable)